# c# linqu and to dictionary, can i check if key exists in the proces?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple question, I am converting sql result using liqu to dictionary it looks like this:

```
            result.ExtendedRelationshipSet = reader.Read().AsParallel()
                                                          .Select(r =>
                   new RelationshipsSyncComp.RelationshipCollection.ExtendedRelationship()
            {
                Id = r.RelationshipId,
                FromItemId = r.fromDocumentId,
                FromItem = new Item() {Id = r.fromDocumentId},
                FromBridgeId = r.fromBridgeId ?? r.fromDocumentId,
                FromDocumentKey = r.fromDocumentKey,
            }).ToDictionary(x => RelationshipsSyncComp.RelationshipCollection
                                                      .RelationshipResultKey(type, x), x => x);
```

Key for the dictionary is build from combining from id and to id, but I noticed there not unique (some transaction bug that sometimes duplicates record in db), so basically there are duplicated entry's.

Can I check using above procedure if key in the dictionary already exists, or ignore duplicate keys?

Comment: if you group by wanted key (after quering the data), and now create your dictionary, you should be okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Lookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) to allow duplicate keys. And use [ToLookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup.aspx) method instead of `ToDictionary()`

If you want to ignore duplicates, you can use DistinctBy before `ToDictionary` from [morelinq](https://code.google.com/archive/p/morelinq/)  or create your own extension

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>
     (this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    HashSet<TKey> keys = new HashSet<TKey>();
    foreach (TSource item in source)
        if (keys.Add(keySelector(element)))
            yield return item ;
 }
```

And then call it before `ToDictionary`

```
     result.ExtendedRelationshipSet = reader.Read().AsParallel()
                                                      .Select(r =>
               new RelationshipsSyncComp.RelationshipCollection.ExtendedRelationship()
        {
            Id = r.RelationshipId,
            FromItemId = r.fromDocumentId,
            FromItem = new Item() {Id = r.fromDocumentId},
            FromBridgeId = r.fromBridgeId ?? r.fromDocumentId,
            FromDocumentKey = r.fromDocumentKey,
        })
       .DistinctBy(x=> RelationshipsSyncComp.RelationshipCollection.RelationshipResultKey(type, x)) 
       .ToDictionary(x => RelationshipsSyncComp.RelationshipCollection.RelationshipResultKey(type, x), x => x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 -  Take first item in case of duplicate keys.

```
      result.ExtendedRelationshipSet = reader.Read().AsParallel().Select(r => new RelationshipsSyncComp.RelationshipCollection.ExtendedRelationship()
        {
            Id = r.RelationshipId,
            FromItemId = r.fromDocumentId,
            FromItem = new Item() {Id = r.fromDocumentId},
            FromBridgeId = r.fromBridgeId ?? r.fromDocumentId,
            FromDocumentKey = r.fromDocumentKey,
        }).GroupBy(g=>RelationshipsSyncComp.RelationshipCollection.RelationshipResultKey(type, x))
          .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.First());
```

Option 2 -  Filter or ignore items having duplicated `Key`.

```
      result.ExtendedRelationshipSet = reader.Read().AsParallel().Select(r => new RelationshipsSyncComp.RelationshipCollection.ExtendedRelationship()
        {
            Id = r.RelationshipId,
            FromItemId = r.fromDocumentId,
            FromItem = new Item() {Id = r.fromDocumentId},
            FromBridgeId = r.fromBridgeId ?? r.fromDocumentId,
            FromDocumentKey = r.fromDocumentKey,
        }).GroupBy(g=>RelationshipsSyncComp.RelationshipCollection.RelationshipResultKey(type, x))
          .Where(e=>e.Count() > 1)  // ignore duplicates
          .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.First());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a .GroupBy() before .ToDictionary() then you can create a dictionary with lists as values.